# trouble assigning new values to mulitple object parameters from nested list

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment

i'm working up a test to populate multiple object's various parameters from a list that comes from an sqlite3 table.

this is the code and the errors:

```py
class thing(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.name = data[0]
        self.spoot = data[1]
        self.lurmz = data[2]
    def __str__(self):
        output = f'{self.name} data → spoot: {self.spoot}, lurmz: {self.lurmz}'
        return output
 
blorp_one = thing(['flarn', 750, 110])
blorp_two = thing(['gleep', 500, 70])
print(blorp_one)    #<-- flarn data → spoot: 750, lurmz: 110
print(blorp_two)    #<-- flarn data → spoot: 500, lurmz: 70

#  data from sqlite3 db
result = [['blorp_one', 'spoot', 3750], ['blorp_one', 'lurmz', 610], 
                    ['blorp_two', 'spoot', 1250], ['blorp_two', 'lurmz', 660]]

result[0][0].result[0][1] = result[0][2]
result[1][0].result[1][1] = result[1][2]
result[2][0].result[2][1] = result[2][2]
result[3][0].result[3][1] = result[3][2]
#  each one → AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'result'

print(blorp_one)    #<-- desired output: flarn data → spoot: 3750, lurmz: 610
print(blorp_two)    #<-- desired output: flarn data → spoot: 1250, lurmz: 660
```

and i've tried these to no avail:

```py
tmp1 = eval(f'{result[0][0]'})
tmp1.result[0][1] = result[0][2]  #<-- object has no attribute 'result'

tmp2 = eval(f'{result[0][1]'})
tpm1.tmp2 = result[0][2]  #<-- ?? doesn't error out, but doesn't change the params

eval(f'{result[0][0]'}).result[0][1]  #<-- nope.  assignment error
```

now i know it's going to be something simple, but i'm not seeing it (maybe because it's Friday?).  can someone kindly re-orient my brain?  thanks.

EDIT:  i understand that strings are immutable.  but i don't know how to take the stored object NAME, which is a string, and use it to assign new values back to it's parameters; in effect use the string to refer to an object...  this seems pretty bog-standard stuff, but for some reason, it's just not clicking in my head.

Comment: Can you (better) explain what you are trying to do with these statements?

Comment: Maybe `tmp1[tmp2] = result[0][2]`?

Comment: i thought the text and the comments were pretty clear: populate new data into multiple objects' parameters from the `results` list, so i'm not sure how to elaborate further.  but do let me know what you think would make that clearer!  i'd like to improve it's readability.  :)

Comment: @ScottHunter  hm.  i'll give that a shot.  stdby!  :)  EDIT:  Nope.  no love.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```py
# no changes here:

class thing(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.name = data[0]
        self.spoot = data[1]
        self.lurmz = data[2]
    def __str__(self):
        output = f'{self.name} data → spoot: {self.spoot}, lurmz: {self.lurmz}'
        return output
 
blorp_one = thing(['flarn', 750, 110])
blorp_two = thing(['gleep', 500, 70])
print(blorp_one)    #<-- flarn data → spoot: 750, lurmz: 110
print(blorp_two)    #<-- flarn data → spoot: 500, lurmz: 70

# data from sqlite3 db
result = [
    ['blorp_one', 'spoot', 3750],
    ['blorp_one', 'lurmz', 610], 
    ['blorp_two', 'spoot', 1250],
    ['blorp_two', 'lurmz', 660]
]

# but changes here:

blorps = {
  'blorp_one': blorp_one,
  'blorp_two': blorp_two,
}

for result in results:
    blorp_name = result[0]
    blorp_attribute = result[1]
    blorp_value = result[2]

    # could also say:
    # blorp_name, blorp_attribute, blorp_value = result

    the_blorp = blorps[blorp_name]
    setattr(the_blorp, blorp_attribute, blorp_value)

print(blorp_one)    #<-- should output: flarn data → spoot: 3750, lurmz: 610
print(blorp_two)    #<-- should output: flarn data → spoot: 1250, lurmz: 660
```

Comment: okay.  i see what you're doing there.  the `blorps` dict is storing the objects with a key... never thought of that.  nice.  :)  thank you.  and `setattr`, i'd forgotten about!  so thanks twice.  :)